# profile face, bad detection with glasses

Tags: android, opencv, detection

I am making an Android application which is based in OpenCV. I have implemented a profile face detector and I use lbpcascade_profileface.xml file. The detector runs correctly but when I put on glasses the detection is worse.

Is it a limitation of file or not? Someone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There's also an xml for glasses. You can run it as well to detect glasses, but it won't give you the face bounding box, just the glasses bounding box.

You can of course train a new cascade with images of people wearing glasses, or if you're willing to consider face detectors outside of OpenCV, you can try one of this API's for face detection:
http://blog.mashape.com/post/53379410412/list-of-40-face-detection-recognition-apis